# Set selected value on html select without using runat=server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html-select

I'm using [this](https://codeb.it/fonticonpicker/) iconpicker plugin to let the user choose an icon and save it on a database. After that, when user go back on the page, I want to load the saved icon as selected value of the dropdown. 
I can't use runat=server on the select because if I do the plugin stop working.
Select code:

```
<select id="ddlIcona" name="ddlIcona" class="myselect">
    <option value="">No icon</option>
    <option>icon-user</option>
    <option>icon-search</option>
    <option>icon-heart</option>
    <option>icon-star</option>
    <option>icon-users</option>
    <option>icon-camera</option>
</select>
```

I don't bother using hidden field to pass value to the server.
How can I do this? Thank you

Comment: Write a dropdown _change_ event and make an _ajax_ call to the server and save the value. On page load select back the saved value.

Comment: Inject a bit of javascript into the page during page load, like this... `document.getElementById("ddlIcona").value = "icon-star";` for example

Comment: I forgot to mention that the dropdown is on a modal popup and I should get the value from the db when user press a button that opens the popup. I tried placing this 
function loadIcon() {var icon = document.getElementById("lblIcona").value;
            document.getElementById("ddlIcona").value = icon; }
and calling in with ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "Javascript", "javascript:loadIcona();", True) but now the popup doesn't show anymore.

Comment: lblicona is a hiddenfield to which I pass the value I want when user press the button to open the popup

Comment: This sounds like an [XY prblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't know how to make the DropDownList work with runat=server, try to find a solution, which is not workiing, and ask about that instead of the original problem: adding runat=server. You maybe needed to ask that first?

Comment: @VDWWD I just assumed it is a limit of the plugin I'm using. Anyhow, can you share some hint on the matter? Thanks

Comment: I think the problem could be that asp renames the ID's of the control when runat=server is present. Try to use `ClientID`. And inspect the HTML for what is actually being generated.

Comment: the plugin is injected onto a select input by this java: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#ddlIcona').fontIconPicker({
            emptyIcon: true,
            hasSearch: false,
            theme: 'fip-darkgrey',
            iconsPerPage:20
        }); // Load with default options
    });

Comment: @VDWWD how can I change this to use clientid?

Comment: Ok, I changed it to document.getElementById('ddlIcona') and the plugin is still showed even if runat=server, now I will try to use simple code behind. Thanks

Comment: Now it works also with asp:dropdownlist awesome! @VDWWD if you post your comment as answer I'll give the correct answer to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspnet renames the ID of a Control, usually when using Master Pages or Controls like Repeater, Gridview etc.

So a control that looks like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Can have an ID of `PlaceHolder1_Label1` in HTML.

For that reason `ClientID` is usually used to make sure the correct ID is referenced in javascript.

```
<script>
    alert('<%= Label1.ClientID %>');
</script>
```